# Missing letters in Urdu text produced after compiling using Xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

I am using MikTex and Textstudio. Besides i have installed the fonts namely "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf" and "Ariel.ttf" before compiling my document. Problem was resolved when i kept "Jameel Noori Nashtaleeq.ttf" in the same folder where my .tex file was saved.  Xelatex was the compiler i used. The text produced was wonderful but with missing letters. Also `\enumerate{}` option doesn't seem to work out by anyways. The complete code for my document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate,caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set all margins (left, right, top, bottom) to 1 inch
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec}  %IMPORTANT. Allows using multiple languages in document. Knows about Urdu
\setmainlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}   % use numerals=eastern if urdu numbers are desired
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf}  % or another
%\newfontfamily\naskh[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arial.ttf}   % or Scheherazade
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin,Scale=1.3]{Times New Roman}  % or XITS
\parindent 0.3in
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section} -}  % add dash to section label. (Default is just section number.)
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}-}   % change enumeration label punctuation to dash. Default is period.
\rightfootnoterule  % force footnote separator rule to appear at right
\title{خوش آمدید}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    گورے بھائی!!!  \\ \\"اسلام علیکم" \\ تمہارا صحتیاب ہونا ہراک کے لئے خوشیوں کی بہار  لاۓ -\\ عافیت اور فضل ربّی تمہاری صحت کو سیراب کرے اور بچھوں کی زندگیوں کو برکتوں اور حکمتوں سے منور کرے- \\  \\  
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
         دہی
         \item 
         ہریرہ
         \item 
         حددیوں کا سوپ
          
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It’s difficult to read your code listing, because it isn't formatted. You can use the button that looks like `{}`, or indent each line by four spaces.

Comment: While this doesn’t solve your problem, `\tracinglostchars=3` on a recent installation will make it a compile error if the document tries to use a character missing from the font, and `\tracinglostchars=2` will print a warning message to the console. It is always a good idea to do this, and will help you spot these bugs. The default behavior, for backward compatibility, is to silently log the warning to the middle of your `.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf and Arial.ttf must be installed provided that these should be in the same directory with the .tex saved file.
2. Replace:
   \setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5,WordSpace=5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf}  and
   \newfontfamily\naskh[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5,WordSpace=1]{Arial.ttf}   with \setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf}
   \newfontfamily\naskh[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arial.ttf}

Comment: so simpler to just say delete `WordSpace=5`  isn't it rather than make people spot the difference?